# HAProxy, Nginx & Node.js SPDY termination

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, haproxy, spdy

I have a Node.js server using [node-spdy](https://github.com/indutny/node-spdy) to run a SPDY server (with HTTP fallback) in `{ plain: true, ssl: false }` mode.

On top of the Node.js server sits Nginx serving and caching static files and proxying requests to Node.js.

On top of Nginx sits HAProxy balancing the load.

When I first implemented SPDY I just used node-spdy to do the SSL encryption inside Node.js, but know I'd like to use HAProxy to terminate SSL and speak plain SPDY or HTTP inside my network. I'm not sure if Nginx can handle non-encrypted SPDY frames.
Any help configuring Nginx and HAProxy to do just that is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx can handle non-encrypted SPDY frame. Simply use "listen" directive without "ssl" part:

```
listen 8000 spdy;
```

"HAproxy (SSL termination) -> Nginx (SPDY) -> your network (HTTP)" setup is described at https://kura.io/2013/07/15/haproxy-nginx-and-spdy-with-ssl-termination-debian-7/